# The conversion of a varchar data type to a datetime data type resulted in an out-of-range value. Datetime error

Tags: sql, datetime

I'm trying to get values whose CreateDate is before 13.12.2016 - 18:30 I have this query :

```
SELECT *
  FROM [myDB].[dbo].[MyTable] WHERE RecordNo is not null AND CreateDate < '13/12/2016 6:30:00 PM'
```

When I run this query, I get this error :

> The conversion of a varchar data type to a datetime data type resulted
>   in an out-of-range value.

How can I fix this? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT *  FROM [myDB].[dbo].[MyTable] WHERE RecordNo is not null AND  
CreateDate < CONVERT(DATETIME,'13/12/2016 6:30:00 PM',103)
```